# Remove token variables

Tags: php, replace

I'm in the process of writing a theme based script and need a way to replace "variables" or tokens that weren't replaced by the script.

The format is:

```
^_variablename_^
```

So say, after processing the following, with variables: name=Adam, Occupation=programmer

```
Hello, my name is ^_title_^^_name_^, and I work as a ^_occupation_^.
```

We'd be left with `^_title_^` still in place.

I need a way to get rid of these, without knowing the name of the "variable".

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process again:

```
$str = 'Hello, my name is ^_title_^Adam, and I work as a programmer.';
$str = preg_replace('/\^_(\w+)_\^/', '', $str);

echo $str;
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/95NkGedh)

Comment: Perfect! Works as expected, does what it says on the box.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Hello, my name is ^_title_^Adam, and I work as a programmer.';
echo preg_replace('/^_[\w_-]+_^/i', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), when substitute variables in so you can simply ignore ones you can't substitute in:

```
$input = 'Hello, my name is ^_title_^^_name_^, and I work as a ^_occupation_^.  ';
$variables = array('name' => 'adam');
$re = preg_replace_callback('/\^_(?<var>.+?)_\^/', function($params) use ($variables) {
        if (isset($variables[$params['var']])) {
            return $variables[$params['var']]; 
        } else {
            return '';
        }   
    },  
$input);

print $re;
```

This uses anonymous function syntax that works since php 5.3.0, you might need to declare a separate callback for this if you want to use it on earlier versions.

Comment: Do you know that `.+?` is the slowest regexp?